# Struts action call to a particular method not working intermittently

Tags: java, spring, struts2

So I am using Struts 2 and I have action calls to specific methods , now my application instance works fine most of the time but intermittently my struts calls after interceptor requests just fade out and don't call the specified method for processing but after a restart of application server again starts working .

Sample code :
Struts.xml

```
<action name="getOktaFactorDetails" class="*.OKTASetupAction"
        method="getFactorDetailsForAccountSecurity" >
        <interceptor-ref name="loggingStack" />
        <result name="oktaAuthChoiceSecurity" type="tiles">oktaAuthChoiceSecurity</result>
    </action>
```

This class has autowiring to dependency for which we are creating a bean id to  with default scope
Spring bean :

```
</bean>
<bean id="OktaApiService" class="*.OktaApiServiceImpl"/>
```

PS : Interceptors never return any error so it's not the interceptors which are causing the issue .
Hoping to get this problem sorted out with all the wisdom you guy's have out there

Comment: So i dig a bit and found whenever this issue is occuring 2022-06-22 05:23:29,103 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory/doGetBean/ and beans.CachedIntrospectionResults/<init> methods are not called when i switched on the trace level logs

Comment: upon restart of the server this issue vanishes and doesn't surface again untill and unless there are CSS changes to jsp calling his action